# Two select statments with union not working

Tags: mysql, union

i am trying to implement following query,

```
     (SELECT
  MAX(final_avg_total.`Provider Name`) AS `Hospital Name`,
  final_avg_total.`DRG Definition`,
  final_avg_total.`Provider Id`,
  SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments) AS avg_payments,
  SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS avg_covered,
  (SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) - SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments)) / SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS total_average,
  1 - (SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) - SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments)) / SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS total_percentage
FROM final_avg_total
GROUP BY final_avg_total.`Provider Id`
ORDER BY total_average DESC LIMIT 0,5)
Union
 SELECT
  MAX(final_avg_total.`Provider Name`) AS `Hospital Name`,
  final_avg_total.`DRG Definition`,
  final_avg_total.`Provider Id`,
  SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments) AS avg_payments,
  SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS avg_covered,
  (SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) - SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments)) / SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS total_average,
  1 - (SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) - SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments)) / SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS total_percentage
FROM final_avg_total
GROUP BY final_avg_total.`total_percentage`
ORDER BY total_average DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

actually both queries are almost same with only Group By is Differing, but i am getting this error.

```
5 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT
  MAX(final_avg_total.`Provider Name`) AS `Hospital Name`,
  fin'
```

Comment: Are you sure that Provider Name is of a type suitable for `MAX`?

Comment: its type is text , but that what i am asked to do, i know its not the best choice , but BOSS is always right

Comment: I removed the Max clause from the query but now i am getting only 5 results i was expecting 10 records

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful to opt for a smaller problem, if possible.
See if you get the same results if you

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW part_one AS ... ;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW part_two AS ... ;

and then

SELECT * FROM part_one

UNION

SELECT * FROM part_two;

Letting a database engine comprehend the work on it piece-wise has helped me in times past. Also can aid code maintenance.
If you get dupes, UNION ALL is another handy arrow in the quiver.

Answer (score 1):

this is just a regular `UNION` with error
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec657/7

and this is the 'same' UNION without error
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec657/8

the only difference is the parenthesis in both case, please be sure to place parenthesis just after the `UNION` or remove it

```
...
ORDER BY total_average DESC LIMIT 0,5) 
Union
 (SELECT --ADDED PARENTHESIS
  MAX(final_avg_total.`Provider Name`) AS `Hospital Name`,
...
ORDER BY total_average DESC LIMIT 0,5) --ADDED PARENTHESIS
```

Comment: i did as you said added parenthesis but i am only getting only 5 records i am expecting 10 records, NO error in the query, its clean now

Comment: you will receive 5 results because the limit `LIMIT 0,5`